# Comparing DistinguishedName of 2 Arrays and get back all the Data

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I have to make a script to get all EoL Windows Machines. But i have to make a Whitelist for some exceptions.

First I get all old Computers:

```
$getad = Get-ADComputer -Filter {
    (operatingsystem -like "*Windows 10*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*16299*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*14393*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*15063*"`) `
    -or (operatingsystem -like "*Windows Vista*") `
    -or (operatingsystem -like "*Windows XP*") `
    -or (operatingsystem -like "*95*") `
    -or (operatingsystem -like "*94*") `
    -or ( operatingsystem -like "*Windows 8*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*9600*") `
    -or (operatingsystem -like "*2000 Professional*") `
    -or (operatingsystem -like "*2000 Server*") `
    -or (operatingsystem -like "*2003*") `
    -or (operatingsystem -like "*Windows NT*") `
    -or ( operatingsystem -like "*Windows 7*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*7601*")
} `
-Properties ('Name', 'operatingsystem', 'DistinguishedName', 'description', 'lastlogondate', 'OperatingsystemVersion', 'Created', 'Enabled', 'SamAccountName')
        
$selectobj = $getad | Select-Object Name, Operatingsystem, DistinguishedName, Description, Lastlogondate, OperatingSystemVersion, Created, Enabled, SamAccountName
```

Then I load the Whitelist into a variable:

```
  $whitelisted = Get-Content "C:\Users\example\Desktop\whitelistedpcs.txt"
```

Then i First empty out a variable (to be sure) and then i compare the computers I got with my Whitelist.

```
$AlertoldComputers = $null

$alertcompdist = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $selectobj.DistinguishedName -DifferenceObject $whitelisted
```

Now my result is a list of all Computers that are not on the Whitelist, but I've just got the Distinguished Name. I need all the Information:

Name, Operatingsystem, DistinguishedName, Description, Lastlogondate, OperatingSystemVersion, Created, Enabled, SamAccountName

I've tried to do it with a `foreach` but then i get no output at all:

```
foreach ($alertcomputer in $alertcompdist) {
    $AlertoldComputers += Get-ADComputer -Filter {(DistinguishedName -like "*$alertcomputer*")} -Properties ('Name', 'operatingsystem', 'DistinguishedName', 'description', 'lastlogondate', 'OperatingsystemVersion', 'Created', 'Enabled', 'SamAccountName') | Select-Object Name, Operatingsystem, DistinguishedName, Description, Lastlogondate, OperatingSystemVersion, Created, Enabled, SamAccountName
}
```

The output should look something like this:

> Name                   : Examplename
>
> Operatingsystem        : Windows 10 Enterprise
>
> DistinguishedName      : CN=Examplename,OU=Bla,OU=Da,OU=computers,OU=dadada,OU=gugu,DC=tra,DC=la,DC=la
>
> Description            : Its just an example
>
> Lastlogondate          : 01.01.1000
>
> OperatingSystemVersion : 10.0 (10586)
>
> Created                : 01.01.1000
>
> Enabled                : True
>
> SamAccountName         : Example

Comment: I reformatted your code a little bit to make it more readable. It shows up, that your filter looks imho really inefficient. Also, consider making your properties to a variable and reuse them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with this?

The aim is to display computers AD informations and with `if ($whitelisted -match $_.DistinguishedName)`, you check if a value is found in the list of hostnames that are whitelisted :

```
$getad = Get-ADComputer -Filter {(operatingsystem -like "*Windows 10*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*16299*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*14393*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*15063*") -or (operatingsystem -like "*Windows Vista*") -or (operatingsystem -like "*Windows XP*") -or  (operatingsystem -like "*95*") -or (operatingsystem -like "*94*") -or ( operatingsystem -like "*Windows 8*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*9600*") -or (operatingsystem -like "*2000 Professional*") -or (operatingsystem -like "*2000 Server*") -or (operatingsystem -like "*2003*") -or (operatingsystem -like "*Windows NT*") -or ( operatingsystem -like "*Windows 7*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*7601*")} -Properties ('Name', 'operatingsystem', 'DistinguishedName', 'description', 'lastlogondate', 'OperatingsystemVersion', 'Created', 'Enabled', 'SamAccountName')

$whitelisted = Get-Content "C:\Users\example\Desktop\whitelistedpcs.txt"

$getad | Select-Object Name, Operatingsystem, DistinguishedName, Description, Lastlogondate, OperatingSystemVersion, Created, Enabled, SamAccountName | ForEach-Object {
    if ($whitelisted -match $_.DistinguishedName) {
        Write-Host "$($_.DistinguishedName) is whitelisted"
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "$($_.DistinguishedName) is not whitelisted" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $_
    }
}
```

Comment: So with your code I get the Computerinformations about the Whitelisted Computers. But i Need the Computerinformation of the non Whitelisted Computers and save them in a Variable. Later i have to make an Alert if there are any Computers in this Variable. I've tried it with -notmatch but then i get those on the Whitelist to

Comment: I just tried and no problem, with `$whitelisted -notmatch $_.DistinguishedName`, it displays all except whitelisted. `$whitelisted` contains only hostnames or more informations?

Comment: Erratum : `$whitelisted` contains distinguished names or names? I'm trying to know what you are comparing between `Get-ADComputer` results and `$whitelisted`. What exactly contains `$whitelisted`?

Comment: Forgot to mention: it contains Distinguished Names.

Comment: I tried it again and with the new code the whitelisted ones are now away (they are marked as Whitelisted so I can now easeli remove them so i can creat my alert. Awsome :)